# API (fully restricted) StrictMode policy violation

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I'm trying to upload an app in the Play Store Console, when I follow the steps inside **Internal Testing**, after a few hours I receive the Pre-launch report with some issues, examples:

[image]

[image]

With some investigation, some people suggest to upgrade this plugin: **@ionic-native/http**
but nothing happens, the error continues in the console.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http 

npm install @ionic-native/http
```

Fixed the issue updating the plugin to version 3.1.0